# From Linux cross compile for Android how to set the api level?

Tags: android, linux, cross-compiling

I have a c source, and under Linux I want to cross compile for Android. I use arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc with -march=armv7-a but it seems that the API level used by the compiler is too high and the executable doesn't work under armv7-a devices. How can I set a lower API level?

Comment: The `-march` option has nothing to do with the Android API, it selects the model of ARM processor being targetted. Why do you think "the API level used by the compiler is too high"?

Comment: Because the executable works in newer android versions and it doesn't work in older ones.

Comment: Are you sure you're running on exactly the same type of ARM processor on the two systems, or does the one with a newer Android version also have a newer ARM processor? Because arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc  doesn't know anything about the Android API, so there's no way to change it.

Comment: Another possibility is that the C library used by your cross-compiler is too recent for older Android systems. You can't change that, you'd need a different cross-compiler that uses an older C library.

Comment: Basically, he problem is that arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc is not a compiler for Android, it's a compiler for ARM Linux, so it doesn't know anything about Android or about Android API levels. If you want to compile for Android, use the Android NDK.